# Why is there many instances of "fsevent_watch" under Ruby in mac?

Tags: ruby, fsevents

Now I have 21 instances of "fsevent_watch" for which the parent process & process group is "ruby".

I am developing a rails project but nothing is currently running now. The server I started earlier was closed by using cntrl+C. I am on a mac.

How is it getting created? Shouldn't it be closed after the ruby application is closed?

Comment: Answer so far: nobody seems to quite know why -> https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/22312

Comment: I saw that prior to posting here, but since it started in 2015, I assumed that the conversation broke off midway. So are you telling that it's still a mystery?

Answer (score 3):

It is caused by `spring` server that is running in the background for your Rails application.

You can check the spring status by,

```
spring status
```

Then, stop the spring server by,

```
spring stop
```

This will kill/close all the active processes that you see.

Comment: I don't have spring running, checked `ps`, and also have `DISABLE_SPRING=true`.  This is either Rails server or Atom editor for me.  Seems to be the `listen` gem we added to our gemfile and environment to help ActiveSupport and Rails 'hotload' code for the server.